# How can I keep my referrer consistent when tracking a subdomain page in a Iframe.

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm not sure how I should describe my situation and if I'm fully understand it.

Suppose we have a visitor flow that looks like the following:

1. User arrives, after a google search, at : `example.com` / referrer is `google.com`
2. Clicks to log in: `sub.example.com/login.aspx` (iframe page) / referrer is `example.com`

I’ve set the CookieDomain to `auto` and added `example.com` to the referral exclusion list. So from what I understand I have the following situation :

- the Client ID stay consistant when I'm moving from step 1 to step 2. good !
- However I'm concerned with the referrer. I would like to keep my google.com  referrer when I'm moving from step one to step two.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options here. Easy solution is to just look at your traffic sources in Acquisition reports in GA :

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033173?hl=en

If you setup CookieDomain and refferal exlusion list correctly "traffic sources" will give you information you need.

Second option(if you really need to override the reffer) is to:

1. pass the "refferer" value from your parent page into your iframe. There are several ways how to do it but that's up to you.(e.g. query string or postMessage to iframe)
2. in your iframe pick this value up and send it to your dataLayer (in example below I name it {{yourValue}} )
3. then in your GTM you can set "reffer" field in your GA Tag for example:

[image]

Let me know if you need more detialed description on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot however I don't understand you answer regarding the first option I have...

Comment: Well it seems like what you are trying to achieve is to know where are your visitors originally coming from. Google Analytics already have this information, it can be found if you login to your GA and go to ACQUISITION reports (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3157419?hl=en#acquisition)... But I don't know if you have different reason why you want to carry refferer to your iframe you can just follow second option.

Comment: Hey Matus thank for the comment. What happen is that the referer I have in my reporting acquisition is wrong (or direct traffic) because it took the URL of the widget embedded in the frame. Does it make sense or I'm missing something ?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail your setup? What is the embeded widget?... From my understanding you have your page "example.com" where you open "sub.example.com" - is that correct? This is very usual setup and GA links it automatically so you shouldn't see wrong traffic in acqusition report - the fact that you do means you must have an issue with your setup.

Comment: the "sub.example.com" is opened in a Iframe. I though it was clear in my question... or maybe there is something I don't understand.... the thing is that I'm using GA debugger to test this and when I'm opening the iframe with my subdomain, the first referrer disappear for "example.com" as a referrer.

Comment: This is clear, what I don't understand is what you mean by: "referer I have in my reporting acquisition is wrong (or direct traffic) because it took the URL of the widget embedded in the frame" - I don't know what widget are you reffering to.

Comment: I shouldn't have said widget. There is no widget nowhere. I just have a simple Iframe opened with a subdomain.